# Reported speech - changing tenses

Tags: reported-speech

My mum says: "I will be sad after he goes back home." so I can say: "She says she will be..."

But what about: "My mum said she will be sad after he goes back home" - reported a moment ago (it is okay, my teacher says so) but do I have to change the tenses if the person still thinks this way?

"My mum said she would be sad after he went back home." - is this correct too?

Answer (score 2):

That shift to **would** (past tense of **will**) is idiomatic, yes.

P.S. You can leave **went** as is. But some speakers wouldn't shift, and would say **goes**.  *My mum said she would be sad after|when he goes home.* Others would shift to **has gone**.  *My mom said she would be sad when he's gone home.*

Comment: What should I do with "after he goes back home"?

Comment: @user252319   "after he goes back home" might imply that he hasn't gone yet. (just my assumption)